# Issue with Comma as a Delimiter in Latin Pig for free text column

Tags: syntax, apache-pig, delimiter

I am loading a file to PigStorage. The file has a column `Newvalue`, a free text column which includes commas in it. When I specify comma as delimiter this gives me problem. I am using following code.

```
inpt = load '/home/cd36630/CRM/1monthSample.txt' USING PigStorage(',') 
            AS (BusCom:chararray,Operation:chararray,OperationDate:chararray,
                ISA:chararray,User:chararray,Field:chararray,Oldvalue:chararray,
                Newvalue:chararray,RecordId:chararray);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is in csv form then you can use [`CSVLoader`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/index.html?overview-tree.html) to load it.  This may fix your issue.

If this doesn't work then you can load into a single chararray and then write a UDF to split the total line in a way that respects the spaces in `Newvalue`. EG:

```
register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myudfs ;
A = LOAD '/home/cd36630/CRM/1monthSample.txt' AS (total:chararray) ;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudf.prepare_input(total) ;
```